# Business user add rows to wiki table

Tags: javascript, wiki, mediawiki, javascript-framework, wikipedia

I am trying to see if its possible to dynamically add/remove rows in a wiki page.

Context:

I have a knowledge base site which is wiki base, that everyone in our company has access to, unfortunately it is very difficult for most user to add rows to a list of problems and solutions. In fact, I worry that if they go into the wiki page code, they might mess something up. I just want a row added to the wiki table, where the user can simply fill up 5 cells (Problem-Name|Customer|Reason|Steps|Resolution), press the "add" button, and the new row is dynamically added to the wiki table. One member suggest JavaScript code added in. Does anyone have any experience doing this with as little code and confusion as possible :-s

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is nothing like that in MediaWiki itself. You should be able to write some JavaScript code to do this, but I'm not sure how much work would that be.

What you can do in MediaWiki itself is to create a [row template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aTable#Row_template), which will make adding a row simpler. For example, after creating a template called `Table row` for the table you're talking about, you could add a row to a table by using the wikitext:

```
{{Table row|Problem-Name|Customer|Reason|Steps|Resolution}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think it will still be a bit difficult and cumbersome for many user. I wonder if adding the JavaScript code will require additional plug in? Can it be as simple as pasting the code on the bottom of the WikiTable?

Comment: I think it won't require a plug in, you can add any JS code to [common.js](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thought as @svick about templates, great idea. To go in a completely different direction, you could make the editing process itself easier by adding a [WYSIWYG](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWYSIWYG) extension.

Warning: the page code will get quite messy!

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like that in this Wiki: http://recepten.wikia.com/wiki/Recepten_Wiki

The feature is called **Instructive Form**
An Instructive Form is an online WYSIWYG editor that displays a web page with fields the user can edit, but is read-only for the remainder. If a field gets the focus, context sensitive instructions and buttons appear to help the user editing the field with the focus by providing things like: field definitions, and style rules, validation results and action buttons for this field.

My username on the wiki is Documentalist. I created this page: http://recepten.wikia.com/wiki/Svick%27s_sandbox so that you can test it without destroying one of the existing pages.

Does this come close enough to what you're looking for?